# Why can't I shuffle the elements in this code?

Tags: javascript, html, object, element, shuffle

I need to shuffle parts of an object in HTML. I found this code to use, but when I execute it, it turns up blank. Do I have an order issue? What do I need to do to fix it? When I put this in JSFiddle it works, but when I put in the following code into CodePen, it doesn't work and the console shows a blank screen. I don't get any error messages, either. (I edited the question to show my work and changes I made).

```
<html>
  <div class="qbdisplay"></div>
  <div class="qbdisplay"></div>
  <div class="qbdisplay"></div>
<script>
  function shuffle(array) {
    for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      var temp = array[i];
      array[i] = array[j];
      array[j] = temp;
    }
    return array;
  };
  var stats = [{
      name: 'Patrick Mahomes',
      team: 'KC',
      overall: 99
    },
    {
      name: 'Lamar Jackson',
      team: 'BAL',
      overall: 97
    },
    {
      name: 'Russell Wilson',
      team: 'SEA',
      overall: 98
    },
    {
      name: 'Deshaun Watson',
      team: 'HOU',
      overall: 95
    },
    {
      name: 'Drew Brees',
      team: 'NO',
      overall: 95
    },
    {
      name: 'Aaron Rodgers',
      team: 'GB',
      overall: 92
    },
    {
      name: 'Ryan Tannehill',
      team: 'TEN',
      overall: 92
    },
    {
      name: 'Kyler Murray',
      team: 'ARI',
      overall: 90
    },
    {
      name: 'Carson Wentz',
      team: 'PHI',
      overall: 88
    },
    {
      name: 'Matt Ryan',
      team: 'ATL',
      overall: 86
    },
  ];
  var shuffled = shuffle([stats]); // take a copy before shuffling
  for (let display of document.querySelectorAll(".qbdisplay")) {
    let {
      name,
      team,
      overall
    } = shuffled.pop();
    display.textContent = name + ' ' + team + ' ' + overall;
  }
</script>


</html>
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/5k20eoug/

Comment: “it turns up blank” - check the *error log/console* as there may be a thrown error, or maybe it just never ran, or ran before those elements could be found/manipulated, or..

Comment: I updated the question. Please let me know if there is something I should change to make it work.

Comment: If the script works in some cases and not in others, showing the script itself is useless. Have you considered linking the codepen where it fails?

Comment: You're running your script before creating the DOM elements it references. Move the `<script>` tag after the `<div>` tags.

Comment: Thank you for the help. When I updated it, it turned up as undefined. I checked to see if all of the names, were right, and I couldn't find an issue. I updated my code in the question and here is a link to the Codepen: https://codepen.io/JGORODN26/project/editor/XNvnMo ; It is under the file "sports_draft.html."

Comment: `var shuffled = shuffle(stats); // take a copy before shuffling`  you double wrapped it in another array.  if you want to make a (shallow) copy use `stats.slice()` or `[...stats]`

Comment: "Uncaught ReferenceError: te32 is not defined" at football_draft.html line 424 on Codepen - likely typo in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[stats]` is an array literal, creating a new array with `stats` as the first element.  (You are double wrapping your stats array).  So `stats===[stats][0]`, and `[stats].name` is undefined so your for loop is throwing an error trying to destructure `{name}`.

To make a (shallow) copy of your array, you can use the spread operator `[...stats]`, or `stats.slice()`:

```
  var shuffled = shuffle([...stats]); // take a copy before shuffling
```

Note: shallow copy means it only makes a copy one level (just the array itself, not the objects within the array).

```html
<html>
  <div class="qbdisplay"></div>
  <div class="qbdisplay"></div>
  <div class="qbdisplay"></div>
<script>
  function shuffle(array) {
    for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      var temp = array[i];
      array[i] = array[j];
      array[j] = temp;
    }
    return array;
  };
  var stats = [{
      name: 'Patrick Mahomes',
      team: 'KC',
      overall: 99
    },
    {
      name: 'Lamar Jackson',
      team: 'BAL',
      overall: 97
    },
    {
      name: 'Russell Wilson',
      team: 'SEA',
      overall: 98
    },
    {
      name: 'Deshaun Watson',
      team: 'HOU',
      overall: 95
    },
    {
      name: 'Drew Brees',
      team: 'NO',
      overall: 95
    },
    {
      name: 'Aaron Rodgers',
      team: 'GB',
      overall: 92
    },
    {
      name: 'Ryan Tannehill',
      team: 'TEN',
      overall: 92
    },
    {
      name: 'Kyler Murray',
      team: 'ARI',
      overall: 90
    },
    {
      name: 'Carson Wentz',
      team: 'PHI',
      overall: 88
    },
    {
      name: 'Matt Ryan',
      team: 'ATL',
      overall: 86
    },
  ];
  var shuffled = shuffle([...stats]); // take a copy before shuffling
  for (let display of document.querySelectorAll(".qbdisplay")) {
    let {
      name,
      team,
      overall
    } = shuffled.pop();
    display.textContent = name + ' ' + team + ' ' + overall;
  }
</script>


</html>
```